# Get the local file path of the modelfield django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a question regarding to the django models.
I have a model 'model1'

```
class model1(models.Model):
dataset = models.FileField(upload_to='estimate/')

def column(self):
    arr = os.listdir('uploads/estimate')
    try:
        dframe = pd.read_csv(f'uploads/estimate/{arr[0]}')
        columns = dframe.columns
        columns_tuple = [tuple([x,x]) for x in columns]
        return columns_tuple
    except:
        return [('---','---')]
```

this model1 is mainly used to upload the csv file and I want to get the column names for the drop down list options for another model 'model2'.

```
class model2(models.Model):
    column = estimate()
    columns = column.column()
    open_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = columns)
    high_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = columns)
    low_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = columns)
    close_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = columns)
    volume_column = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = columns)
```

Initially the directory uploads/estimate is empty, hence the model1.column() will return `columns = [('---','---')]`, but when I upload the csv file into model1, model2 will not update the drop down list option.

I am not sure any other way that can read the csv file so I use the `pd.read_csv`, it's because I don't know how to use the object `dataset`, I tried using `self.dataset.name` or `self.dataset.path` to get the local file path but system said that it does not have these attributes. So I eventually used os.listdir to locate the file

Appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `FileSystemStorage` that should be only used for your dataset fields.

Try like this:

```
class CustomStorages(FileSystemStorage):
    @cached_property
    def base_location(self): # override this where you dataset located
        return self._value_or_setting(self._location, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    @cached_property
    def location(self): # or override this where you dataset is located
        return os.path.abspath(self.base_location)
```

and attach it to your FileFILED

```
class model1(models.Model):
    dataset = models.FileField(upload_to='estimate/', storage=CustomStorages)
```

Django `FileSystemStorage` is default storage and by default it's location gets from `settings.py` file.

So you have to define custom `FileStorage` when your data is in different location.

So after you configure what suggested above.

and populate your file fields like this.

```
import os
os.rename('dataset.csv', 'newdataset.csv')
dataset = model1()
dataset.myfile.name = 'newdataset.csv'
dataset.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried follow your way and when I put `storages=CustomStorages`, the system gives me an error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'storages'. And after that, may I know what is the use of `os.rename('dataset.csv', 'newdataset.csv')`? Why should I change the file name?

Comment: It will `storage` not `storages` Please check the answer again

Comment: For your infomation, this is my media url and media root in settings.py
``
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'uploads'
MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
``

Comment: The error's gone! Thank you so much. May I know what is the use of `os.rename('dataset.csv', 'newdataset.csv')`? Why should I change the file name?

Comment: in what folder your  `estimate/upload` located?

Comment: The whole file path will be uploads/estimate/xxx.csv

Comment: It will be saved inside the django folder, I tried to make it pd dataframe with the code `dframe = pd.read_csv(f'uploads/estimate/{arr[0]}')`. `arr` is the directory list in the folder so I only get the only file inside this folder, i.e. `arr[0]`